# How can I add a 5 second delay to this setInterval based sprite animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css-sprites

I have a sprite which runs using the setInterval method, It runs all the time and moves the css background position (x) by 100/(number of images -1) every interval of 60ms. When the position hits 96% i reset it to 0. Simple. This is the formula for animating a sprite with percentages.

Now I just want to add a 5 second delay between each time it runs (every time it hits 96% x position, wait 5 seconds and then run again). What is the easiest way to achieve this.. I tried wrapping the setInterval in another set interval but the problem here is that only runs it more often (and makes it go crazy). I know there is also a method called `clearInterval` and i am thinking maybe using that every few seconds would work but then how do i restart the animation afterwards?? I need it running over and over with a 5 second delay in between each run.

```
    function animateAlways() {

        var positionHeadDot = 0;
        var interval = 60;
        const diffHeadDot = 3.703704;


        shadeSparkle = setInterval(() => {
            /////////////////////HeadDot////////////////////////////////////
            document.getElementById("imageHeadDot").style.backgroundPosition =
                `${positionHeadDot}% 0%`;
            if (positionHeadDot < 96) {

                positionHeadDot = positionHeadDot + diffHeadDot;

            }
            else {

                positionHeadDot = 0;

            }
        }, interval); 

    } 

    animateAlways()
```

Comment: Not sure to follow. This executes every 60 milliseconds. Where/when do you want another delay?

Comment: Do you want to animate all the icons with a 60ms interval, then wait 5000ms and restart to animate at 60 ms delay?

Comment: after it has run through the whole sprite. so after it hits a position of 96% wait for 5 seconds.. and run again

Comment: yes Eineki thats what im trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is easier when you convert your `setInterval` code to use `setTimeout`. Then you can distinguish between the progress and final step and provide an adjusted timeout value:

```
function animateAlways() {
    var positionHeadDot = 0;
    var interval = 60;
    var delay = 5000;
    const diffHeadDot = 3.703704;

    function animate() {
        /////////////////////HeadDot////////////////////////////////////
        document.getElementById("imageHeadDot").style.backgroundPosition =
            `${positionHeadDot}% 0%`;
        if (positionHeadDot < 96) {
            positionHeadDot = positionHeadDot + diffHeadDot;
            setTimeout(animate, interval);
        }
        else {
            positionHeadDot = 0;
            setTimeout(animate, delay); // 5 second wait.
        }
    }
    animate();
}
```

Comment: great thanks, could not get my head around it but this is exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an outer `setInterval`, then use `clearInterval` to clear the inner interval instead of setting the position back to 0:

```js
function animateAlways() {
  var positionHeadDot = 0;
  var interval = 60;
  const diffHeadDot = 3.703704;

  shadeSparkle = setInterval(() => {
    /////////////////////HeadDot////////////////////////////////////
    document.getElementById("imageHeadDot").style.backgroundPosition =
      `${positionHeadDot}% 0%`;
    if (positionHeadDot < 96) {
      positionHeadDot = positionHeadDot + diffHeadDot;
    } else {
      clearInterval(shadeSparkle);
    }
  }, interval);
}

animateAlways();
setInterval(animateAlways, 5000);
```

```css
#imageHeadDot {
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/smiley.gif');
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageHeadDot"></div>
```